# Impersonate standard user

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to make a running process of mine which is elevated to restart explorer using the standard user token.

What I'm doing is first I run the main process as an administrator, then I take a snapshot of the running:

```
if (Process32First(hSnapshot,&pe32))
    {
        do
        {
            if (!wcsicmp(pe32.szExeFile, L"explorer.exe"))
            {
                DWORD dwExplorerSessId = 0;
                if (ProcessIdToSessionId(pe32.th32ProcessID, &dwExplorerSessId) && dwExplorerSessId == dwSessionId)
                {
                    dwExplorerLogonPid = pe32.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            }

        } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe32));
    }

    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
```

then once I get the PID of explorer which is running under the standard user account, I call:

```
OpenProcessToken(hProcess,TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE
            ,&hPToken))
```

then I call:

```
ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hPToken);
```

and finally I taskkill explorer.exe and shell execute it again but its running under the administrators privileges.

Its as if the impersonateLoggedonUser is not working. Although its returning true and GetLastError() returns 0;

I have also tried using CreateProcessAsUser() but this always gives an ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND:

```
    STARTUPINFO si;
    GetStartupInfo(&si);                
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    TCHAR tchcmd[MAX_PATH];
    _tcscpy(tchcmd, _T("explorer.exe"));
    PVOID penv;
    CreateEnvironmentBlock(&penv, hToken, FALSE);
HANDLE hNewToken;
DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenImpersonation, &hNewToken);
    CreateProcessAsUser(, NULL, tchcmd, 0, 0, 0, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, penv, 0, &si, &pi );
```

Any Ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the Process32First/Next functions are preserved for backward compatibility and don't always return prefect results. They don't work reliably on 64 bit machines, and they often return less than the actual number of svchost.exes. Hoe that helps :)

Comment: @BillyONeal: It will return all processes... if you have the priv SE_DEBUG

Comment: Even with `SeDebugPrivilege` it does not always return the correct number of svchosts. It has problems with anything started before the Windows API is initialized (earlier in the NT booting process.) `EnumProcesses()` is the only (documented) function that always returns the correct answer.

Comment: Hi

I have found that the client process token does not hold the  SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME which is required for CreateProcessAsUser to work, I also found that by default the fore mentioned Security is not granted by default to administrator accounts. Can it be programatically granted to the process as its running?

Answer (score 3):

Are you calling [DuplicateTokenEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446617(VS.85).aspx) on the token before using it? You should.

Instead of [ImpersonateLoggedOnUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378612(VS.85).aspx), you could more easily just call [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429(VS.85).aspx).

**Edit to match yours:**

- Your CreateProcessAsUser by the way should be passing: `CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT` for the `dwCreationFlags`.
- You should also be error checking your `CreateEnvironmentBlock`.
- You should also be adjusting the [Ace](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165194) of the `desktop` and `window station`.
- Instead of specifying the path directly in CreateProcessByUser you should first expand any environment variables in the string by using ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser.  This will for example convert: `%windir%\explorer.exe` to `C:\windows\explorer.exe`

.

```
wchar_t szNewCommandLine[MAX_PATH];
if(!::ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser(hNewToken, tchcmd, szNewCommandLine, MAX_PATH - 1))
{
    DWORD dwExpandEnvLastError = GetLastError();
    //error handling
}
```

[For further reading please see this post on Session, Window Station, and Desktop management](http://brianbondy.com/blog/id/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops).

Comment: I tried it also but its returning INVALID_PARAMETER_ERROR

I edited the question for the method I'm using..

Comment: What is returning INVALID_PARAMETER_ERROR?  Are you calling DuplicateTokenEx?

Comment: I have made adjustments to the code and added the duplicatetokenex and gave it a TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS right, but now when I call CreateProcessAsUser it gives error code 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Any Ideas

Comment: Try specifying the full path of explorer.exe.  You didn't set the working directory and maybe the CreateEnvironment block is not working as you expected.  You could possibly try calling LoadUserProfile Win32 API to help.

Comment: So how can I check if the environment block is working, I am debugging the code and there is no error returned from creating the environment block. And I'm not sure how LoadUserProfile can help.

Comment: Added more details, what happens when you call CreateProcessAsUser with `"C:\\windows\\explorer.exe"` directly?

Comment: "So how can I check if the environment block is working" - via its return value.

Comment: Well after hours of trials and errors I finally reached the point where CreateProcessAsUser returns 1314... Now its more of a privilege problem. The problem is when I try to set the privileges (SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME and SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME) but it seems that the token does not hold those privileges to begin with as AdjustTokenPrivilege returns ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED. I'm using the MSDN example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446619%28VS.85%29.aspx if thats worth something.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the ace to the desktop and windows station and you need to set the desktop member to winsta0\default

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem when trying to run a program as a standard user from an installer started with elevated admin privileges. After trying ( and failing miserably ) to do this using CreateProcessAsUser function I have stumbled upon a solution that uses ShellExecute from IShellDispatch2 interface.

It can be used to start a process as current interactive user. For complete implementation look here:
https://code.google.com/p/mulder/source/browse/trunk/Utils/nsis_stdutils/Contrib/StdUtils/ShellExecAsUser.cpp?r=327

Hope this helps!