# How to invoke a function impersonating another user instead of SYSTEM

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

A Win32 API was invoked in my DLL, which will be loaded by SYSTEM user, and that API returns different results depending on current user, so I cannot get the results corresponding to the current user, how can I invoke that API under current logon user context when the DLL is running in SYSTEM context?

Comment: Is the DLL within a Windows service? Impersonation with an ordinary process is usually very hard. You would need user name and password to get current user's token...

Comment: Yes, it turns out that the design is inappropriate, if we want to invoke an API in user context, we should make it a user service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made some research and concluded this (I'm not a Win32 API expert, but I'm really interested in it):

You can use [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612), which asks for a [primary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721603.aspx#_security_primary_token_gly) or an [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721588.aspx#_security_impersonation_token_gly) token handle (with at least `TOKEN_QUERY` in both, `TOKEN_DUPLICATE` on a primary token, or `TOKEN_IMPERSONATE` on an impersonation token).

It would be very easy, if you had the current logged on user token, and the right privileges, you'd just use `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`, call the API function that you want, and then call [`RevertToSelf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379317) to return to its original owner token.

But it's not that easy to get the current logged on user token. You'd have to either use [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184) specifying the user's name and password (which doesn't seem right), or own a Windows service with sufficient privileges to let you call [`WTSQueryUserToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383840), which may differ from what type of project you are developing.

Or, if you are really willing to do this with an ordinary process, you could also explore the [Authentication Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374731), where you can take advantage of the newly Windows UAC and security contexts, which may be a little complex to work with.

There is also this method which I'm not sure if it works: [Impersonate standard user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2281823/260411) (getting the token by using [`OpenProcessToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295) on `explorer.exe`).

Some links I found useful:

- [MSDN - Client Impersonation (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376391)
- [MSDN - Access Tokens (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909)
- [MSDN - LsaLogonUser function (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378292)
- [A Simple Impersonation Program Example](http://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/accesscontrollistaclexample6_1.html)
- [CodeProject - User Impersonation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21050/Security-User-Impersonation)
- [CodeProject - Vista UAC: The Definitive Guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide)

I suggest: make sure you really need to impersonate an user when calling the API function you mentioned, before going on. See if there is another path to accomplish what you want.

You could also specify which API function you are trying to use, which may redirect you to another simpler question.