# Starting process as different user

Tags: c++, winapi

I hope someone can help me with this! I have a similar problem as decribed in:
[Impersonate standard user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281823/impersonate-standard-user)

I want to be able to create a process as standard user from application that runs with elevated admin privileges ( UAC Execution level: requireAdministrator ). The user starts the application by borrowing privileges from one of the administrator accounts.

I have succeeded in acquiring a handle to explorer.exe process of this user and it is stored in variable m_hExplorerProc. After that I proceed as follows:

```
HANDLE hProcToken = NULL;

BOOL success = OpenProcessToken(m_hExplorerProc, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hProcToken);

BOOL lookupRet = LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME,
    &(tokenPrivs.Privileges[0].Luid));
tokenPrivs.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tokenPrivs.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
BOOL adjustRet = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hProcToken, FALSE, &tokenPrivs, 0, NULL, NULL);

lookupRet = LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME, &(tokenPrivs.Privileges[0].Luid));
tokenPrivs.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tokenPrivs.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
adjustRet = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hProcToken, FALSE, &tokenPrivs, 0, NULL, NULL);

HANDLE hDuplicatedToken = NULL;
success = DuplicateTokenEx(hProcToken,
    TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
    NULL,
    SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL::SecurityImpersonation,
    TOKEN_TYPE::TokenPrimary,
    &hDuplicatedToken);
int err = 0;
if(FALSE == success)
    err = GetLastError();

LPCTSTR appName = L"C:\\testapp.exe";

PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
ZeroMemory(&procInfo, sizeof(procInfo));

STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
startupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_NORMAL;
startupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;

success = CreateProcessAsUser(hDuplicatedToken, appName, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE,
    NULL, L"C:\\", &startupInfo, &procInfo);

if(FALSE == success)
    err = GetLastError();
```

The process is not created and last error is 1314 which translates to: "A required privilege is not held by the client".

In this code I am just trying to execute a dummy app but I eventually want to run browser which was selected as default by this user. Does someone have an idea what am I doing wrong, or perhaps suggest an alternate solution to my problem?

Comment: Are you trying to mug some other process to get its credentials? Think about the security implications if that would be possible.

Comment: @MSalters: I don't see the security implications in going from an administrator to a less privileged user. With that said, it's a common problem that an installer launches an application with administrator privileges, which causes issues.

Comment: @dauphic: In Windows, permissions are not fully ordered. Trivially, an Administrator account usually does not have permission to write to someone else's profile. More importantly, `Administrator` and `SYSTEM`  are distinct.

Comment: @MSalters: As dauphic said, I am going from administrator to less privileged user. In fact, the problem I am trying to solve is to open default browser of standard user from an installer that he started using elevated admin privileges.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a security issue. If you could do that as Administrator, you could also run `CMD.EXE /C DEL /S %APPDATA%`. And as I said, you can't just write to someone elses profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not cool to answer your own question but three month have passed and still no one suggested an answer.

I have not been able so solve the problem described above using function CreateProcessAsUser but I have stumbled upon an alternate method using ShellExecute from IShellDispatch2 interface which enables you to start a program as current interactive user. Complete code can be found at:
https://code.google.com/p/mulder/source/browse/trunk/Utils/nsis_stdutils/Contrib/StdUtils/ShellExecAsUser.cpp?r=327

I hope this helps someone with a similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but I would like to add something useful (I think). If you want to use `CreateProcessAsUser` you need privileges, which can be obtained by impersonating a powerful token. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833235/is-there-a-workaround-for-createprocesswithtokenws-cmdline-arguments-max-lengt/47950905#47950905) for detail.