# Is there a workaround for CreateProcessWithTokenW's cmdline argument's max length?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create an unelevated process from an elevated process on Windows 7-10.

I used the following as a reference:

[FAQ: How do I start a program as the desktop user from an elevated app?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2009/06/06/faq-how-do-i-start-a-program-as-the-desktop-user-from-an-elevated-app/)

Now, this method works wonderfully, however due to a possible legacy check, it seems that `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` only allows the `cmdline` argument to be less than or equal to 1024 characters.

The `cmdline` I'm required to pass through is far more than that, which causes an `E_INVALIDARG` error.

Has anyone run into the same issue as me?  If so, how did you work around this absolutely ridiculous 1024 character limit?

Comment: I have no knowledge of the NT security system. Still, if all else fails I suppose you might try a wrapper executable, launched via `CreateProcessWithTokenW` and forwarding the command-line through other a different channel.

Comment: use `CreateProcessAsUser` instead.

Comment: I find it odd that `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` would be limited to only 1024 characters, considering that [the limit in `CreateProcess()` is 32767 characters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031210-00/?p=41553). But, that is what the documentation says, so be it. If you have control over the source of the EXE being launched, you might want to consider other methods of passing large data through `CreateProcess...()` APIs, such as [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031211-00/?p=41543/) or [this](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/undocumented-createprocess).

Comment: @RbMm It seems that CreateProcessAsUser works if a specific privilege is enabled. However based on the article this non-elevated snippet works, it requires a different privilege. 

TOKEN_PRIVILEGES only allows 1 privilege count. If you know of a way to have multiple privileges, it'd be much appreciated

Comment: @J.M - *If hToken is a restricted version of the caller's primary token, the SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME privilege is not required.* - if you want create non-elevated process from own elevated - you not need special priviledges

Comment: in any case unclear what you want to do. what is your current process.(session, token). are you want exec child in some session. exist many different ways how exec child process with another token/session. impossible give exactly answer without understand context

Comment: `TOKEN_PRIVILEGES only allows 1 privilege count.` ??? what ?? `If you know of a way to have multiple privileges, it'd be much appreciated` - ?????

Comment: @RbMm the "ANYSIZE_ARRAY" is hardcoded to 1. However the MSDN documentation says "The constant ANYSIZE_ARRAY is defined as 1 in the public header Winnt.h. To create this array with more than one element, you must allocate sufficient memory for the structure to take into account additional elements.". 

I've done this already with an anonymous structure with the same exact data members and their respective types however with CreateProcessAsUser it still is saying "ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD". So it does seem that I need that SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME privilege if I'm getting that error code.

Comment: @J.M - so what ?? you dont know how work with variable size data ? and how this related to question at all ? `If you know of a way to have multiple privileges, it'd be much appreciated` - what is nonsense ? `CreateProcessAsUser it still is saying "ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD"` - how i say this is depended from which token you try use. if you use  restricted version of own token - you not need this priviledge

Comment: your question is incomplete - not clear context, what you try todo. with which privileges run your process. how you get token to child. in which session you plan exec child. ..

Comment: @RbMm relax dude. It's related to the question since you gave me the suggestion of using CreateProcessAsUser. I've now attempted to do so and running into an issue. I figured instead of making a new question, I'd ask the person suggesting the solution directly. If you'd just read the article/link I put, you'd understand what I'm trying to achieve. Now as I stated previously, I'm still having an issue with this approach due to getting that error code. Which if you look at the documentation, means I need the SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME privilege alongside the INCREASE_QUOTA one from the article.

Comment: @J.M - at first you have zero knowledge about token privileges and all related to this. and second you ignore my question about context - what you try todo

Comment: @RbMm Nevermind. Thank you for your helpful feedback.

Comment: again - why you not simply create restricted token from self elevated token ??? by `CreateRestrictedToken(hToken, LUA_TOKEN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &hLowToken)` ? and use it with `CreateProcessAsUser` - in this case you not need any priviledge

Comment: article from your link - not professional written, solution is bad here. if you exactly need run medium app, from full elevated - use `CreateRestrictedToken` + `SetTokenInformation(hLowToken, ::TokenIntegrityLevel` + `CreateProcessAsUser`

Comment: no problem - code which i post perfect worked, but i not sure are you need exactly this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using `CreateProcessAsUserW()` instead? I know it requires special privileges, but if your process is running as administrator, there is a way to overcome it.

The idea is to impersonate a **powerful token** before calling the API. A powerful token is defined as **a token that possesses all desired privileges**.

First, enumerate process ID via API like `NtQuerySystemInformation()`. For each process ID, open the process token and use `GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, ...)` to get information of what privileges are possessed by the token. If the token possesses all privileges we want, we may duplicate an impersonation token out from it by `DuplicateTokenEx(..., TokenImpersonation, &hTokenImp)` (and stop enumerating of course).

Now that we have the powerful token, we shall examine the desired privileges of it, **see if they are all enabled**. Check status with `PrivilegeCheck()` and enable it with `AdjustTokenPrivileges()`. Finally, let current thread impersonate the token by `SetThreadToken(NULL, hTokenImp)`, call the `CreateProcessAsUserW()` however you like, and stop impersonation by `SetThreadToken(NULL, NULL)`.

As for the token for `CreateProcessAsUserW()`, I would recommend you to use primary token of current user session by `WTSQueryUserToken()`, because it would work as expected even if you do [OTS elevation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687(v=vs.85).aspx). Last time I tried to use Linked Token as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2010/05/31/dealing-with-administrator-and-standard-users-context/), and found it would not work with OTS elevation.

Here is a test code in ANSI C. When running as administrator, it will run another instance of itself un-elevated and show the command line length. And yes, `CreateProcessAsUserW()` supports command-line longer than 1024. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include "EnumProcessesId.h"

#define MY_LuidEqual(a, b)  \
    ( ((a)->HighPart == (b)->HighPart) && ((a)->LowPart == (b)->LowPart) )

static LPVOID MyAllocZero(SIZE_T cb)
{
    LPVOID ptr = CoTaskMemAlloc(cb);
    if (ptr) { ZeroMemory(ptr, cb); }
    return ptr;
}
static void MyFree(LPVOID ptr)
{
    CoTaskMemFree(ptr);
}

static DWORD MyWTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(void)
{
    typedef DWORD(WINAPI *fn_t)(void);
    fn_t fn = (fn_t)GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("kernel32"),
        "WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId");
    if (fn) { return fn(); }
    return 0;
}

static BOOL MyWTSQueryUserToken(DWORD sessId, HANDLE *phToken)
{
    typedef BOOL(WINAPI *fn_t)(DWORD, HANDLE*);
    fn_t fn = (fn_t)GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("wtsapi32"),
        "WTSQueryUserToken");
    if (fn) {
        return fn(sessId, phToken);
    }
    return FALSE;
}

static BOOL MyPrivIsEnabled(HANDLE hToken, LUID const *pPrivLuid)
{
    BOOL isEnabled = FALSE;
    PRIVILEGE_SET ps = { 0 };
    ps.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    ps.Privilege[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT;
    PrivilegeCheck(hToken, &ps, &isEnabled);
    if (!isEnabled) {
        ps.Privilege[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        PrivilegeCheck(hToken, &ps, &isEnabled);
    }
    return isEnabled;
}

static HRESULT MyEnablePriv(HANDLE hToken, LUID const *pPrivLuid, BOOL enable)
{
    BOOL ok = FALSE;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = { 0 };
    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = enable ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : 0;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = *pPrivLuid;
    ok = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL);
    return ok ? S_OK : HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
}

typedef struct {
    /* in : */
    LUID const *pLuidAPT;
    LUID const *pLuidIQN;
    LUID const *pLuidTCB;
    /* out : */
    HANDLE hptPowerful;
} MyEnumPowerfulTokenData_t;

static BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumPowerfulTokenProc(DWORD pid, void * user)
{
    DWORD const ProcessQueryLimitedInfo = 0x1000;
    MyEnumPowerfulTokenData_t *pData = user;
    BOOL ok = FALSE, wantContinue = TRUE;
    HANDLE hProc = NULL;
    HANDLE hProcToken = NULL;
    DWORD i = 0, cbTP = 0;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES *pTP = NULL;
    BOOL gotAPT = FALSE, gotIQN = FALSE, gotTCB = FALSE;

    /* Get process token */
    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
    if (!hProc) {
        hProc = OpenProcess(ProcessQueryLimitedInfo, FALSE, pid);
    }
    if (!hProc) goto eof;
    ok = OpenProcessToken(hProc, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, &hProcToken);
    if (!ok) goto eof;

    /* Check if token possesses desired privileges */
    GetTokenInformation(hProcToken, TokenPrivileges, NULL, 0, &cbTP);
    if (!cbTP) goto eof;
    pTP = MyAllocZero(cbTP);
    if (!pTP) goto eof;
    ok = GetTokenInformation(hProcToken, TokenPrivileges, pTP, cbTP, &cbTP);
    if (!ok) goto eof;
    for (i = 0; i < pTP->PrivilegeCount; ++i)
    {
        LUID const *pThat = &(pTP->Privileges[i].Luid);
        if (gotAPT && gotIQN && gotTCB) {
            wantContinue = FALSE;
            pData->hptPowerful = hProcToken;
            hProcToken = NULL; /* to avoid eof CloseHandle() */
            break;
        }
        else if (!gotAPT && MY_LuidEqual(pThat, pData->pLuidAPT)) {
            gotAPT = TRUE;
        }
        else if (!gotIQN && MY_LuidEqual(pThat, pData->pLuidIQN)) {
            gotIQN = TRUE;
        }
        else if (!gotTCB && MY_LuidEqual(pThat, pData->pLuidTCB)) {
            gotTCB = TRUE;
        }
    }
eof:
    if (pTP) { MyFree(pTP); }
    if (hProcToken) { CloseHandle(hProcToken); }
    if (hProc) { CloseHandle(hProc); }
    return wantContinue;
}

static HRESULT MyCreateProcess(LPWSTR szCmdLine)
{
    HRESULT hr = 0;
    BOOL ok = FALSE;
    LUID luidAPT = { 0 }; /* SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME */
    LUID luidIQN = { 0 }; /* SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME */
    LUID luidTCB = { 0 }; /* SE_TCB_NAME */
    MyEnumPowerfulTokenData_t enumData = { 0 };
    HANDLE hptPowerful = NULL; /* primary/process token */
    HANDLE hitPowerful = NULL; /* impersonation token */
    HANDLE hptCurrSessUser = NULL;
    DWORD dwCurrSessId = 0;
    STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };

    ok = LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME, &luidAPT)
        && LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME, &luidIQN)
        && LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_TCB_NAME, &luidTCB);
    if (!ok) {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()); goto eof;
    }
    enumData.pLuidAPT = &luidAPT;
    enumData.pLuidIQN = &luidIQN;
    enumData.pLuidTCB = &luidTCB;
    hr = EnumProcessesId_WinNT(MyEnumPowerfulTokenProc, &enumData);
    if (FAILED(hr)) goto eof;
    hptPowerful = enumData.hptPowerful;
    if (!hptPowerful) {
        hr = E_UNEXPECTED; goto eof;
    }

    ok = DuplicateTokenEx(hptPowerful, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenImpersonation, &hitPowerful);
    if (!ok) {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()); goto eof;
    }
    if (!MyPrivIsEnabled(hitPowerful, &luidAPT))
    {
        hr = MyEnablePriv(hitPowerful, &luidAPT, TRUE);
        if (FAILED(hr)) goto eof;
    }
    if (!MyPrivIsEnabled(hitPowerful, &luidIQN))
    {
        hr = MyEnablePriv(hitPowerful, &luidIQN, TRUE);
        if (FAILED(hr)) goto eof;
    }
    if (!MyPrivIsEnabled(hitPowerful, &luidTCB))
    {
        hr = MyEnablePriv(hitPowerful, &luidTCB, TRUE);
        if (FAILED(hr)) goto eof;
    }
    ok = SetThreadToken(NULL, hitPowerful);
    if (!ok) {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()); goto eof;
    }

    dwCurrSessId = MyWTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
    ok = MyWTSQueryUserToken(dwCurrSessId, &hptCurrSessUser);
    if (!ok) {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()); goto eof;
    }
    ok = CreateProcessAsUserW(hptCurrSessUser, NULL, szCmdLine, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
    if (!ok) {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()); goto eof;
    }

eof:
    SetThreadToken(NULL, NULL);
    if (hptCurrSessUser) { CloseHandle(hptCurrSessUser); }
    if (hitPowerful) { CloseHandle(hitPowerful); }
    if (hptPowerful) { CloseHandle(hptPowerful); }
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("HRESULT = 0x%.8X \n", hr);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        WCHAR szMsg[999] = {0};
        wsprintfW(szMsg,
            L"lstrlenW(GetCommandLineW()) = %i \n",
            lstrlenW(GetCommandLineW()));
        MessageBoxW(NULL, szMsg, L"Test", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    else
    {
        WCHAR szMyExePath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
        WCHAR szCmdLine[9999] = {0}, *p;
        GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szMyExePath, MAX_PATH);
        wsprintfW(szCmdLine, L"\"%s\" ", szMyExePath);
        for (p = szCmdLine; *p; ++p);
        while (p < (szCmdLine + 9999 - 1))
        {
            *p++ = 'a';
        }
        MyCreateProcess(szCmdLine);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I will leave the implementation of `EnumProcessesId_WinNT()` to you. The prototype of the function is:

```
/* return TRUE to continue */
typedef BOOL(CALLBACK *EnumProcessesId_Callback_t)
    (DWORD pid, void * user);

EXTERN_C
HRESULT __stdcall
EnumProcessesId_WinNT(
    EnumProcessesId_Callback_t fnCallback,
    void *user
);
```

Comment: I'll look into this when I get back to work next week. Thanks so much for the help! I'll keep you updated whenever I get to it :D

Comment: Thank you so so much. Your implementation seems to work wonders! Question, my current "EnumProcessId" uses EnumProcesses and just calls the callback on each process ID. Is that really necessary to call that function on every single process running at the time?

Comment: @J.M Not every. When the callback returns `FALSE`, you don't have to call it anymore. The ultimate goal of `MyEnumPowerfulTokenProc` is to get a powerful token. If the token is there, there is no point to call it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

for exec not elevated process from our elevated (in same session) we need do next:

- create restricted token from our elevated token by
  CreateRestrictedToken with `LUA_TOKEN`
- set medium intergity level in new token
- call `CreateProcessAsUser` - note that

> If hToken is a restricted version of the caller's primary token, the
>   SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME privilege is not required.

```
ULONG LowExec(PCWSTR lpApplicationName, PWSTR lpCommandLine)
{
    HANDLE hToken, hLowToken;

    ULONG cb = GetSidLengthRequired(1);

    TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL tml = { { (PSID)alloca(cb) } };

    ULONG dwError = NOERROR;

    if (CreateWellKnownSid(WinMediumLabelSid, 0, tml.Label.Sid, &cb) &&
        OpenProcessToken(NtCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_QUERY | 
        TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY, &hToken))
    {
        BOOL fOk = CreateRestrictedToken(hToken, LUA_TOKEN, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &hLowToken);

        if (!fOk)
        {
            dwError = GetLastError();
        }

        CloseHandle(hToken);

        if (fOk)
        {
            if (SetTokenInformation(hLowToken, ::TokenIntegrityLevel, &tml, sizeof(tml)))
            {
                STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si)};
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

                if (CreateProcessAsUser(hLowToken, lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, 0, 0, TRUE, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
                {
                    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
                }
                else
                {
                    dwError = GetLastError();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dwError = GetLastError();
            }

            CloseHandle(hLowToken);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }

    return dwError;
}
```